# How to solve circular dependency scenario while executing http calls which require authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, design-patterns, circular-dependency

I am working on a project which requires me to execute standard HTTP calls with session tokens.
I am building a custom HTTP client, with a custom authenticator, something like this:

```
Client client = Client.Builder().withConfig().withAuthenticator(Authenticator);
```

and my authenticator is an interface

```
public interface Authenticator{
  SessionToken getSessionToken(); // so that different authentication methods can be supported
}
```

Now, for executing a request, I need to get a session token, which I obtain by calling `authenticator.getSessionToken()`. However, the authenticator has to call the backend to get the token, for which it requires a client, leading to a circular dependency. How do I solve this? One approach is to create a separate authentication client, which I pass in the constructor of the Authenticator Implementation, but the package imports would still show circular dependency. Is there a better way to design this?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the `Client` doesn't really need an `Authenticator`; it needs a `SessionToken`. One way to achieve that is to replace the `withAuthenticator()` method by `withSessionToken()`. The obvious implementation would be for that method to directly accept a `SessionToken`; but you might also consider that `Authenticator` is a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) and therefore can be represented as a [`Supplier<SessionToken>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

Either way, if you replace the `Client` dependency on `Authenticator` with either `SessionToken` or `Supplier<SessionToken>`, you can break the circular dependency.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I'll be creating the client instance once for the entire app scope, so session token will have to be refreshed, which means a new session token for each request in the worst case. So your first approach won't be possible. I like the supplier one though, will definitely try it out, but this authenticator won't be a functional interface, there are some other methods too here :)